# HTTPURLConnection Status 200 but inputstream is null

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-200

I have the following configuration: a Glassfish server in witch I am running a Java web services. During a process task it is necessary to connect ,with HTTP GET, to an other web services with a HTTPURLConnection. This connection run real unstable sometimes it is possible to send 1200 request to this services with out problems, but some times it create an error. The HTTP Status is 200 but if I try to read from the Inputstream, its null. Also all Logs show nothing special. In the end of the request i close the reader and after this i disconnect the connection. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to first get some eyes on the request/reponse. You can use tcp monitor/fiddler/etc as a proxy server to see the raw message. Once you have the proxy server setup you can see if theres anything wrong with the payload.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks I see now that I have a HTTP Error 504. Means I have to increase the cache of my Glassfish?

HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Wed, 03 Dec 2014 21:35:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 16:35:28.838

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.